# How to merge rows to contain a list of the values in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a set of DataFrames that contain tweets with timestamps. In order to create a daily time series I tried to merge the rows by day in each DataFrame.

My solution was this code in a loop:

```py
df_temp = df[df['created_sec'].isin(range(date_start,date_end))]
df_temp = pd.DataFrame(zip(df_temp.T.values), index= df_temp.columns)
data    = data.append(df_temp.T)
```

While the results seem ok, the loop is terribly slow and complicated without reason. Also, if I merge rows again like this, the result will be lists in lists, which is not desirable too.

---

The process is supposed to be as follow:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [1,2,3,4,5],
                   'text': ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo']})
```

1. The DataFrame:

```
        time    text
    0   1       foo
    1   2       bar
    2   3       foo
    3   4       bar
    4   5       foo
```

2. After merging time `1,2,3` & `4,5`:

```
        time        text
    0   [1, 2, 3]   [foo, bar, foo]
    1   [4, 5]      [bar, foo]
```

3. After merging indices `[1,2,3]` & `[4,5]` at a later time:

```
        time            text
    0   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] [foo, bar, foo, bar, foo]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1st question

```
s = df.groupby(df.index//3).agg(list)
s
        time             text
0  [1, 2, 3]  [foo, bar, foo]
1     [4, 5]       [bar, foo]
```

2nd question

```
s.sum().to_frame(0).T
              time                       text
0  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  [foo, bar, foo, bar, foo]
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
def summarize(df,start,end,columns):
    row = {}
    for col in columns:
        print(df[col][start:end].tolist())
        row[col]=df[col][start:end].tolist()

    df =df.append(row,ignore_index=True)
    df=df.drop(df.index[range(start,end)])
    df = df.reset_index()
    return df
```

Answer (score 0):

## You can try creating a function that consolidate your data into lists as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [1,2,3,4,5],
                   'text': ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo']})
df

    text    time
0   foo     1
1   bar     2
2   foo     3
3   bar     4
4   foo     5

def consolidate(df, break_index): #df = dataframe, break_index = index where you want to create the first list
    text = [[x for x in df['text'][0:break_index]]]
    time = [[x for x in df['time'][0:break_index]]]
    if break_index == len(df):
        pass
    else:
        time.append([x for x in df['time'][break_index:]])
        text.append([x for x in df['text'][break_index:]])
    df2 =pd.DataFrame({'time':time,'text':text})
    return df2

consolidate(df,3)
    text             time
0   [foo, bar, foo]  [1, 2, 3]
1   [bar, foo]       [4, 5]

consolidate(df,5)
    text                        time
0   [foo, bar, foo, bar, foo]   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```